# Java copy elements in column from String array to new int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

just after a bit of help with something that I cant seem to get right.

I have the following code which displays the values in a csv file. This is working.

```
while(file.hasNext()){
    String data = file.nextLine();
    String[] values = data.split(",");
    for(String index : values){
        System.out.printf("%s \t", index);
    } 
    System.out.println();
}
```

The code displays:

```
1    John Smith    Engineering
2    Jim Jones     Cooking
```

I want to take the values just from *values[0]* (which are the ID's - 1,2) and copy them into a new int array so I can pass this to other methods to perform searches and whatnot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Do you know how many lines there will be in the file? An array needs its size known when allocating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand your question fully, but you can try this:

```java
String[] str_array = {...};
int[] int_array = {...};

int_array[index] = Integer.parseInt(str_array[index]);
```

This way you can add a String to an int array, watch out for NumberFormatExceptions.

Edit:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>(); // IDs: 1, 43, 23...
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Reading from console
int input = scanner.nextInt();

if (ids.contains(input)) {
  // true
} else {
  // false
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not going about this the right way. I want to create another method that prompts the user to enter an ID and checks if the entered ID is included in the csv. I thought this would best be done through an int array with the values of the ID? do you have another suggestion?

Comment: In that case a List  (e.g. ArrayList) would come in handy. You don't have to know it's size when allocating and the `contains()` method seems just right for your problem. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I will give it a shot tonight! thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just save values[0] into a seperate list and convert it to an array. If you know the number of ids you can directly save your ids into an array.

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
while (file.hasNext()) {
    String data = file.nextLine();
    String[] values = data.split(",");
    if (values.length >= 1) {
        ids.add(values[0]);
        
        for (String index : values) {
            System.out.printf("%s \t", index);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}

String[] idsArray = new Integer[ids.size()];
ids = ids.toArray(idsArray);
// use idsArray
```

Comment: There is no int array in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:)

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    while(file.hasNext()){
        String data = file.nextLine();
        String[] values = data.split(",");
        for(int key=0;key<values.size();key++){
            if (!map.containsKey(key)){
                map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            map.get(key).add(values[key]);
        } 
    }
    Integer[] items = new Integer[map.get(0).size()];
    for (i = 0; i < map.get(0).size() ; i++) {
       items[i]=Integer.valueOf(map.get(0).get(i));
    }
```